# Create a website that prints 'Hi' and 'Hello' on two separate lines, using Shiny for Python

Tags: python, py-shiny

This is a simplification of my general problem, so I would like to stick to the rubric given in the example. Packages like `htmltools` are welcome, although I have already tried a few "solutions" using this, given by ChatGPT. I am generally running a neural network inside of `app()`, and I want the output to look something like

The result from neural network X is: 137

The result from neural network Y is: 17

Here is my code

```
from shiny.express import render

@render.text()
def app():
    return 'Hi \n Hello'
```

When I run `shiny run --reload shinyfoo.py` in the terminal, I receive the URL for the resulting website, but unfortunately the website simply yields

Hi Hello

I have also tried using the `htmltools` package and using `<br>` instead of `\n`, but this doesn't work either. I do not know R, so I would like to stick with Python for this problem. Unfortunately, all similar posts I have seen seem to use R.

Comment: A newline in HTML is just whitespace and will get printed as a space. Instead, add an actual html linebreak `<br/>`

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I have tried this. The website then shows 
'Hi <br/> Hello' @Grismar